# Make HTML page size 0 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is there any way to reduce the size of a html page to width and height = 0 from javascript/jquery
I am calling this html page from inside and iframe and the iframe resizes to the html page size
and I would like the iframe to disappear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the actual `iframe` you from the `iframe` you will need to do it by accessing the parent of the `iframe`.  So say we have two pages:

**parent.html:**

```
<htmL>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="parentFrame" src="./child.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**child.html:**

```
<htmL>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="hide me" onclick="$('#parentFrame', window.parent.document).hide();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

We get the parent using window.parent.document, then we can access whatever we want in the parent from there, in this case the iframe itself which we simply hide.

Comment: Thanks Rob! But my iFrame contents and the iFrame code are on different servers. Will this still work then?

Comment: No, in that case you will have XSS issues, perhaps you can detect it somehow though, maybe when the `hide` button is clicked you can add a hash to the url so window.location.href += '#blah', then having a setInterval in your parent page that checks the iframes url if it contains the #blah hash you can hide it, remove it, etc...haven't tested this yet though.